# How to make a child div alone responsive using css?

Tags: html, css

This may be a very basic question, but is it possible make a child  alone responsive, when the containing parent div is not?

So basically, this is the html I have:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#child {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20%;
    width: 50% !important;
}

#parent {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Now, I want to make the child responsive without affecting the parent div by just using css. http://jsfiddle.net/o5xajj9s/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the child div being sized relative to the parent, it would have to be sized relative to something else.

An example of this would be using viewport width / viewport height.

http://jsfiddle.net/o5xajj9s/1/

This div would always be 50% of the viewport width (window size on a computer).
Combining this with media queries where you need it I think would solve your issue.

```
div {
  width: 50.0vw !important; 
}
```